# A question about dummy pronoun

Tags: syntax

According to Wikipedia, A dummy pronoun is a  pronoun that fulfills a syntactical requirement without providing a contextually explicit meaning of its referent. *It* is often a dummy pronoun in English expressions. Then is there any other word that can be deemed as dummy pronoun in specific situations?

Comment: ***one** pops into head*

Comment: @iBug — ***One*** is an indefinite pronoun, it's not dummy, there's always an antecedent behind ***one***, someone or something it refers to, and you can always replaced ***one*** by a noun phrase, a test for ‘dumminess’ the dummy _it_ cannot pass.

Comment: @YellowSky _One_ (the one Bill was talking about, not the true pronoun as in ‘one does not simply walk into Mordor’) **is** used with the indefinite article, both in the phrase ‘not a one’ (plus ‘nary a one’ and similar constructions), and also when modified: ‘a single one’, ‘an extra one’, etc.

Comment: In addition to dummy "it", existential "there" as in "There is a fly in my soup" is a dummy pronoun. However, the pro-form "one" that occurs in such examples as "She left us six pears; this one is riper than the other ones" is not a dummy pronoun but a common noun because it occurs readily with determiners and, like most common nouns, but unlike pronouns, it inflects for number.